# How to change alias to table name automatically in case of oracle?

Tags: oracle, alias

We are currently analyzing hundreds of queries.

E.g

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a.hobby,
       b.desc
FROM   tablename a,
       table2    b
WHERE  a.id = b.id;
```

or

```
SELECT id,
       NAME,
       hobby
FROM   tablename;
```

above these can be change like below?

```
SELECT tablename.id,
       tablename.name,
       tablename.hobby,
       table2.desc
FROM   tablename tablename,
       table2    table2
WHERE  tablename.id = table2.id;
```

or

```
SELECT tablename.id,
       tablename.name,
       tablename.hobby
FROM   tablename tablename;
```

Do you know any tools or methods that have the ability to change them?

Comment: Why would you want to change the way they're aliased, if they're already fully aliased? IMO, using the full table name as the alias name clutters up the query and makes it harder to read.

Comment: These are just SQL statements... where do they come from? Are these "Views" in your system or are these statements that are coming from applications? There's no tool to help with this that I'm aware of. If these are views you can pull all of the DDLs and write your own script to parse them and flip out the aliases, but that's going to be a hell of a lot of work with almost no gain except to fit a superfluous standard. If it were me, I'd find somewhere else to focus my efforts.

Comment: The reason for doing this is I want to find specific colunm for specific tablename among many(more than 100 queries) queries text.

Comment: [This Blog](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2008/10/dbadependencycolumns.html) seems to extend `ALL_Dependencies` to include columns...which seems to be what you're after; and is pretty cool.  Makes use of `sys.dependency` which appears to be the oracle system table tracking the column relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Ananymous block for another query :

```
 declare
    v_query varchar2(4000) :='SELECT a.id,
           a.name,
           a.hobby,
           b.desc
    FROM   tablename a,
           table2    b
    WHERE  a.id = b.id';
    tab_list varchar2(4000);
    v_newquery varchar2(4000);
    v_tab_alias varchar2(100);
    v_tabname varchar2(500);
    v_alias varchar2(40);
    tab_cnt NUMBER :=0;

    begin
    -- table list
    select replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(regexp_replace(v_query,'FROM|WHERE','@'),'[^@]+',1,2)||chr(10),chr(10),null)
    into tab_list
    from dual;

    -- no of tables 
    select REGEXP_COUNT(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(regexp_replace(v_query,'FROM|WHERE','@'),'[^@]+',1,2)),',')+1
    into tab_cnt
    from dual;

    For i in 1..tab_cnt
    LOOP

    select TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(tab_list,'[^,]+',1,i))
    into v_tab_alias
    from dual;

    -- replace alias tablename for the column list

    select TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_tab_alias,'[^ ]+',1,1))
    into v_tabname
    from dual;

    select TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_tab_alias,'[^ ]+',1,2))
    into v_alias
    from dual;

    select regexp_replace(v_query,v_alias||'\.',v_tabname||'.')  
    into v_newquery
    from dual;

    v_query:= v_newquery;

    -- replace alias tablename in FROM clause
    select regexp_replace(v_query,v_alias||'\,',v_tabname||',')  
    into v_query
    from dual;

    END LOOP;

    -- replace alias last tablename before WHERE clause
    select regexp_replace(v_query,v_tab_alias,v_tabname||' '||v_tabname)  
    into v_query
    from dual;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_query);

    END;
```